# Accesing variable in nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, module

Im' trying to build my first module in nodejs.
I have this code working perfectly :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db;
var io = require('socket.io-client');
const notifier = require('node-notifier');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    createDb();
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log("socket connected");
    });
    socket.on('message', (contenu) => {
        console.log('message received');
        console.log(contenu);
        notifier.notify(contenu.contenu);
    });
    socket.emit('message', { contenu : 'test'});
  res.render('index', { title: 'Accueil' });
});

/* SQLite */
function createDb() {
    console.log("createDb chain");
    db = new sqlite3.Database('./database_institut-villebon.db', createTable);
}

function createTable() {
    console.log("createTable etudiants");
    db.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etudiants");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS etudiants (Nom TEXT, NumeroGroupe INTEGER, NumeroCandidat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Filiere TEXT)", insertRows);
}

function insertRows() {
    console.log("insertRows in etudiants");
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO etudiants VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        stmt.run("John Doe",i,i,"S");
    }

    stmt.finalize(readAllRows);
}

function readAllRows() {
    console.log("readAllRows etudiants");
    db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, Nom, NumeroGroupe, NumeroCandidat, Filiere FROM etudiants", function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            console.log(row.id + ": " + row.NumeroCandidat +","+ row.Filiere);
        });
        closeDb();
    });
}

function closeDb() {
    console.log("closeDb");
    db.close();
}

function runChain() {
    createDb();
}

module.exports = router;
```

But when i try to put it in a module it say that the table "etudiants" doesn't exist ...

This is my module :

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

"use strict";

/* SQLite */
var BddUtils = function () {
    console.log("createDb chain");
    this.database = new sqlite3.Database('./database_institut-villebon.db');
}

BddUtils.prototype.closeDb = function () {
    console.log("closeDb");
    this.database.close();
}

BddUtils.prototype.readAllRows = function() {
    console.log("readAllRows etudiants");
    this.database.all("SELECT rowid AS id, Nom, NumeroGroupe, NumeroCandidat, Filiere FROM etudiants", function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            console.log(row.id + ": " + row.NumeroCandidat +","+ row.Filiere);
        });
        this.database.closeDb();
    });
}

BddUtils.prototype.insertRows = function() {
    console.log("insertRows in etudiants");
    var stmt = this.database.prepare("INSERT INTO etudiants VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        stmt.run("John Doe",i,i,"S");
    }
    //stmt.finalize(this.readAllRows());
}

BddUtils.prototype.createTable = function () {
    console.log("createTable etudiants");
    this.database.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etudiants");
    this.database.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS etudiants (Nom TEXT, NumeroGroupe INTEGER, NumeroCandidat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Filiere TEXT)", this.insertRows());
}

BddUtils.prototype.init = function () {
    this.createTable();
}

exports.BddUtils = exports = new BddUtils();
```

I have been looking for an issue and i found that if I don't drop the table everything works !
So i suppose that the "insertRows" function is called before the create table... but it's a callback function ....
Any help will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I'm maybe on something :

> The context of the function (the this object inside the function) is
>   the statement object. Note that it is not possible to run the
>   statement again because it is automatically finalized after running
>   for the first time. Any subsequent attempts to run the statement again
>   will fail.
>
> If execution was successful, the this object will contain two
>   properties named lastID and changes which contain the value of the
>   last inserted row ID and the number of rows affected by this query
>   respectively. Note that lastID only contains valid information when
>   the query was a successfully completed INSERT statement and changes
>   only contains valid information when the query was a successfully
>   completed UPDATE or DELETE statement. In all other cases, the content
>   of these properties is inaccurate and should not be used. The .run()
>   function is the only query method that sets these two values; all
>   other query methods such as .all() or .get() don't retrieve these
>   values.

So it's possible that my this.database is not in the current context anymore... don't know how to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to wrap your CREATE TABLE statement into a [Database.serialize() function](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow#databaseserializecallback).

> **Database#serialize([callback])**
>
> Puts the execution mode into serialized. This means that at most one
>   statement object can execute a query at a time. Other statements wait
>   in a queue until the previous statements are executed.

This ensures the CREATE TABLE statement gets executed in isolation.

The example that comes from the documentation:

```
db.serialize(function() {
  // These two queries will run sequentially.
  db.run("CREATE TABLE foo (num)");
  db.run("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)", 1, function() {
    // These queries will run in parallel and the second query will probably
    // fail because the table might not exist yet.
    db.run("CREATE TABLE bar (num)");
    db.run("INSERT INTO bar VALUES (?)", 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, have a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is a more generic (and very handy) concept to gain control of any (asynchronous) flow.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've tried with a Promies but it said that this.database is undefined... (cannot read property run of undefined). I'm having trouble with scope ..

var p1 = new Promise(
     function(resolve,reject) {
       console.log("createTable etudiants");
       this.database.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etudiants");
       this.database.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS etudiants (Nom TEXT, NumeroGroupe INTEGER, NumeroCandidat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Filiere TEXT)");
     }
   );

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using db.serialized()

```
BddUtils.prototype.createTable = function () {
    var db = this.database;

    db.serialize(function() {
      console.log("createTable etudiants");
      db.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etudiants");
      db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS etudiants (Nom TEXT, NumeroGroupe INTEGER, NumeroCandidat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Filiere TEXT)");
      var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO etudiants VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          stmt.run("John Doe",i,i,"S");
      }
      stmt.finalize(function(){
        console.log("readAllRows etudiants");
        db.all("SELECT rowid AS id, Nom, NumeroGroupe, NumeroCandidat, Filiere FROM etudiants", function(err, rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                console.log(row.id + ": " + row.NumeroCandidat +","+ row.Filiere);
            });
            db.close();
        });
      });
    })
 }
```